# JSNI code not working from client browser with Java 1.8 plugin

Tags: javascript, swing, gwt, applet, jsni

In GWT I have overridden the functionality of Java buttons. By this way Swing buttons were hidden and a web-based application can replace them with HTML/image buttons, controlling the applet from Javascript.
So this was the purpose overall.
Below mentioned code is working fine from client browser with java plugin 1.6. How ever same is not working from client browser with Java plugin 1.8.
Method 'jsCommand' is not getting called.

```
public class UploadApplet extends JApplet {

   private native String appletCommand(String cmd) /*-{
       return $doc.Uploader.jsCommand(cmd);
    }-*/;
}
```

Please help, thanks in advance.

`**@UPDATE**`

This is an Applet for which a wrapper is added for the GWT JavaScript code to access the values. The wrapper is done using JSNI(JavaScript Native Interface) which is GWT code.

Comment: I don't get it: is this an applet? (then no GWT!) a GWT app with some emulation of the applet and swing API? something in between?

Comment: Thanks Thomas for the reply.Yes, this is an Applet and is embedded inside a GWT UI. The Applet's functionality is called from within GWT UI by using JSNI. The Applet is basically a file browser, which asks user to pick a file and pass the selected file name to GWT UI for further processing.